# How to fix data reading and table formatting problem with web scrapin in R

Tags: r

The first is how to programmatically access each of the 11 pages in this online table.

Since this is a simple html table, using the "Next" (next) button will take us to a new page. If we look at the URL on the Next page, we can see the page number in the query parameters.

"
... tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano / ordenes-compra? page = 1 & number_order = & estado ..."

We know that the pages are numbered starting with 0 (because "next" takes us to page 1), and using the navigation bar we can see that there are 11 pages. The httr package offers many very useful tools for handling html requests. Among those tools is the httr :: parse_url function that returns a list with the components of a URL.

```html
url_params <- httr::parse_url("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=1&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")

# Not all results returned were included below for the sake of keeping the example concise

$scheme
[1] "https"

$hostname
[1] "colombiacompra.gov.co"

$path
[1] "tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra"

$query
$query$page
[1] "1"

$query$number_order
[1] ""
```

Use the query parameters to construct a series of rvest :: read_html () calls corresponding to the page number by simply using lapply and paste0 to replace the page =. We can also save some time by coercing data.frame into the app.

```
pages <-
  lapply(0:11, function(x) {
    read_html(x = paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=", 
                         x, 
                         "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")) |>
      html_table() |>
      data.frame()
  })

do.call(rbind, pages)

But I have the following error
```

```html
  > url_params <- httr::parse_url("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=1&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")
    > 
    > pages <- lapply(0:11, function(x) {
    +   rvest::read_html(x = paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=", 
    +                          x, 
    +                          "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")) |>
    Error: inesperado '>' in:
    "                         x, 
                             "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")) |>"
    >       html_table() |>
    Error: inesperado '>' in "      html_table() |>"
    >       data.frame()
    data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
    >   })
    Error: inesperado '}' in "  }"
    > 
    > do.call(rbind, pages)
    Error in do.call(rbind, pages) : objeto 'pages' no encontrado
    > 
    > do.ca
    Error: objeto 'do.ca' no encontrado
```

how can I solve that?

Comment: The error you are getting suggests that you are using an R version that does not recognize the new pipe `|>`. I.e., that you are using R < 4.1.

Comment: Furthermore, https://colombiacompra.gov.co is very likely to kick you out or ban your IP if you do not include a pause between calls.  I.e., add a pause to your loop or create a function that has a pause in it.

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo traer todos los registros en la columna Instrumento sin limitarlo a solo "tool = IAD% 20Software% 20I% 20-% 20Microsoft"?

Comment: El servidor usa un API Rest, donde la query está compuesta por pares de variable y unidad. Al parecer el par que requieres tiene la variable llamada "tool". Tienes que cambiarle la unidad por alguna otra que no sea la de Microsoft.
`tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft`
Al parecer puedes ver el nombre de las variables disponibles en el menu de título 'Instrumento'.
Por ejemplo, esta query busca en 'Grandes Superficies':
`tool=Grandes%20Superficies`

Comment: I don't want it to have a filter, I want it to bring me all the "tools" records, without limiting it to one, and to have a single base with all the "tools" records.

Comment: Then modify your SO question, because you explicitly state that you want `&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft` in the fifth line of your code.
That said, this query might get you what you want:
`?number_order=&state=issued&entity=&tool=&date_to=2021-07-01&date_from=2021-06-01`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map_df` to read the html table from each url and combine it into one table.

```
urls <- paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=", 
       0:11, 
       "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")

library(rvest)

res <- purrr::map_df(urls, ~.x %>% read_html() %>% html_table) 

res
# A tibble: 578 x 6
#    `Orden de Compra` `Entidad Estatal`  `Fecha de la or… Estado Instrumento Total
#               <int> <chr>              <chr>            <chr>  <chr>       <chr>
# 1             72683 UNIDAD ADMINISTRA… 2021-07-16 20:0… Emiti… IAD Softwa… $453…
# 2             72670 SUPERINTENDENCIA … 2021-07-16 16:5… Emiti… IAD Softwa… $252…
# 3             72648 BOGOTA D.C - UNID… 2021-07-16 14:4… Emiti… IAD Softwa… $179…
# 4             72638 ESTABLECIMIENTO P… 2021-07-16 14:1… Emiti… IAD Softwa… $1,7…
# 5             72631 INPEC - ESTABLECI… 2021-07-16 12:5… Emiti… IAD Softwa… $1,6…
# 6             72605 POLICIA NACIONAL … 2021-07-15 20:0… Emiti… IAD Softwa… $2,9…
# 7             72524 FOGAFIN            2021-07-15 08:4… Emiti… IAD Softwa… $5,9…
# 8             72502 INSTITUTO DE FOME… 2021-07-14 22:2… Emiti… IAD Softwa… $1,9…
# 9             72471 ANTIOQUA - MUNICI… 2021-07-14 09:5… Emiti… IAD Softwa… $28,…
#10             72433 AGENCIA DE RENOVA… 2021-07-13 16:2… Emiti… IAD Softwa… $282…
# … with 568 more rows
```

Comment: I don't want it to have a filter, I want it to bring me all the "tools" records, without limiting it to one, and to have a single base with all the "tools" records. ¿How i do it?